# Why i get error when try post request with headers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, axios

I create orders for goods in the online store but when I do POST request

```
addToCart: function () {
      axios.post('http://localhost:8081/orders/',{
        quantity: '1',
        product: this.id,
        user: this.$store.getters.getUser._id
      },{
        headers: {
          Authorization:"Bearer " + this.$store.getters.getToken
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log('sucsecc')
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
    }
```

Here in jsx code

```
<div class="descCont"><button class="add" @click="addToCart">Add to Cart</button></div>
```

I get err :

```
POST localhost:8081/orders 404 (Not Found)
Error: Request failed with status code 404
at createError (createError.js?16d0:16)
at settle (settle.js?db52:18)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?ec6c:77)
```

I checked the correctness of the incoming data in the body and everything is 
correct there. Can you tell me what I was wrong about? Server code on Node.js(orders.js)

```
router.post('/',checkAuth,upload.single('productImge'), (req, res, next) => {
    Product.findById(req.body.productId)
        .then(product => {
            if (!product){
                return res.status(404).json({
                    message: 'Product not found'
                })
            }
            const order = new Order({
                _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                quantity: req.body.quantity,
                product: req.body.productId,
                user: req.body.user
            })
            return order.save()
        })
        .then(result => {
            res.status(201).json({
                message: 'Order stored',
                createdOrder: result

            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            })
        })
})
```

In main file:

```
const ordersRoutes = require('./routes/orders')
```

Comment: Are you sure the server is running on port 8081? Is it the correct endpoint URL? Do you have a proxy/firewall?

Comment: Get request work! But post return err.

Comment: The post route does not have 'orders' in it's path, or did you not include the code for this?

Comment: I test in PostMan and all works.

Comment: Does your Postman test also include the trailing slash in the request url?

Comment: No.Here example `localhost:8081/orders`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you post a product with a wrong Id? With your first statment your first if statement will return a `404` error.
Please be aware that `product: this.id,` might be `undefined`